# BitmapData manipulation

Tags: actionscript-3

The simplest way to apply stretching/rotation to a bitmap seems to be something akin to the following:

```
bmp = //some bitmap
var bounds:Rectangle = getBounds(bmp)
var stretchX:Number, stretchY:Number, rotate:Number;
//assign stretch & rotate vars
var transform:Matrix = new Matrix(stretchX * Math.cos(rotate), -stretchX * Math.sin(rotate),
                                  stretchY * Math.sin(rotate,   stretchY * Math.cos(rotate));
bmp.bitmapData.draw(bmp, transform);
```

I've heard, though, that the draw method is inefficient compared to most of the other methods in the Bitmap and BitmapData classes. Given that my project is very sensitive to inefficiency (read: is intended for real-time operation), I would rather implement something hackish and efficient than something straightforward and inefficient. Having scoured the API, I can't seem to come up with anything... Any ideas, or am I stuck using the draw method?

Comment: The matrix here won't be entirely correct - ignore that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working only with bitmaps (BitmapData → BitmapData). I would suggest to use `clone(), copyPixels()` methods and apply transformation on the result: `myClonedBitmap.transform.matrix = neededTransformations.`

> clone() method lets you clone, or sample, bitmap data from one BitmapData object to another. When called, the method returns a new BitmapData object that is an exact clone of the original instance it was copied from.
>
> The copyPixels() method is a quick and easy way of copying pixels from one BitmapData object to another. The method takes a rectangular snapshot (defined by the sourceRect parameter) of the source image and copies it to another rectangular area (of equal size). The location of the newly “pasted” rectangle is defined within the destPoint parameter.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that property because I had the inherited properties hidden, apparently... If a bitmap with non-null transform properties is sampled with clone or copyPixels will the transformed image be sampled, or the original?

Comment: Also: what is your preferred name for accreditation in the 'thanks' portion of my package's 'readme.txt'? I think you've earned it :)

Comment: No, transformation Matrix of original Bitmap isn't part of the BitmapData. So you need to copy transformation from the original Bitmap, apply changes to Matrix, and apply new matrix to a new Bitmap. For `thanks` - Nicolas Siver is ok, It's my name ;)